# Oracle adf: no response from action and action listener on master-detail commandLink

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, master-detail

I have master-detail tables. In the detail table, one of  the columns is a af: commandLink. However, the link does not navigate out of the page at all. In fact, I made a dummy action listener with sysout to see if it would invoke it at least, but it didn't.

I am not vested in adf life-cycle but my page is in a bounded task flow of two pages only. When I placed a button above the two tables on the same page with the same action it worked. It seems that the problem is only in the detail table. I once tried invoking a value change listener in the same way and it did not work. I tried all the column selection values: none and single, but with no luck.

Is this a common bug? If so, what is the work around?

Thank you,

Comment: Did you try to set commandLink attribute "partialSubmit" to "true" ?

Comment: Can you mention what version of adf you are using? I'm using 11.1.2.4, and i have a lot of same examples in my current project, and all works perfect.

Comment: I just did, and it did not work. I am using 12c.

Comment: Maybe there is a hidden error? Try to change log level to FINEST